# SAS output statement and keep statement

Tags: sas, output

I run a program like this:

```
data january;
set allmonths (keep=product month num_sold cost);
if month='jan' then output january;
sales=num_sold*cost;
put sales;
keep product sales;
run;
```

The dataset january contains two variables: product and sales. But sales value is missing.

```
product sales
a        .
```

I kind of understand why sales value is missing because it is not defined in the dataset allmonth before output statement.

Then why this variable can be included in the dataset january if output statement doesn't have it. Keep statement can include every variable listed to every dataset, then why no value be written to the dataset.

I think I might know the reason. Keep statement is about variables, output is about observations.

But I still want to ask and learn.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep is one of those SAS statements that is processed during the compilation phase for the data step before it starts processing the data. The decision on which variables to keep in the output table january has been decided (due to the keep statement) before your if and output statements are executed. An equivalent way of writing your code which may make it clearer is:

```
data january (keep= product sales);
set allmonths (keep=product month num_sold cost);
if month='jan' then output january;
sales=num_sold*cost;
put sales;
run;
```

To simplify it and get it to do what you probably want:

```
data january(keep=product sales);
set allmonths(keep=product month num_sold cost);
where month='jan';
sales=num_sold*cost;
run;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `OUTPUT` statement runs immediately.  So it is writing the record before you have calculated a value for SALES.  Try adding another PUT statement before the IF/THEN/OUTPUT statement and you can see the values that will be output.

For this problem you probably want to use a subsetting IF statement or WHERE statement instead of explicitly running an OUTPUT statement.  If you remove the OUTPUT statement then the data step will automatically output the records at the end of the data step.

```
data january;
  set allmonths;
  if month='jan';
  sales=num_sold*cost;
  keep product sales;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you! The answers from you and Paul described how Output and Keep statement works in data step. Very helpful. Thank you all!